# Can't add tags to the page head for my content at another publisher, can the canonical be embedded in the body?

Tags: canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have published some good articles to a technical community.
Actually, these articles have been ranked as the first result in google and I would like to add my original article as canonical but I don't have any control to do that!

I just have an HTML code without a **head** or **body** tag!

So in this case, how can I set canonical?

Should I add it as below at the beginning of the HTML code,

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/page.php" />
```

I know it will be ignored because it's not located in the head tag, so Is there any workaround to set canonical?

Or just add my article as a refrence?

Comment: I this could work, you could certainly boost your site by hiding such canonicalizations on high-ranked popular sites. In fact, that site may have (or might have in the future) their own canonical-machanism, e.g., if your specific article can be reached on their site via different means, and a conflicting secondary canonical tag would beak that. In the end, you can only ask *them* to address the problem

Comment: I assume you don't have access to set an HTTP response header either?

Comment: Thanks all, I don't have any access, just for the content editor to type content and can be switched to HTML format without head and body!